# Regex - White Space

Tags: css, regex

I have a string coming out as:

```
<span class="abc"> test </span> styletext
```

I want to grab just the `styletext` part which is dynamic and give it some css styles.

Can I use regex to select the whole part after the white space and apply the style? How do I target the part after the white space?

Comment: So you have something like this `</span style="height: 20px;">` and you want to move that to the `<span>`-tag? Do you have the string in a variable? If so in which language? Like PHP, JSP, ASP?

Comment: I am already getting within span tag - and have some dynamic text after this span end tag which I want to style, want to select this part with regex

Comment: why not style the first span, then override span 'abc' with what you don't want?

Comment: I dont want any styling within span, I just want the styletext to be bold, within my code if I add a class with text bold to style text alone-even the text inside span is becoming bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as a regex:

```
^/span\s*(.*)
```

*You may need to escape the "\" depending on the language you are using.*

The text captured in the group will be the style text.

It "translates" as: starting at the beginning of the string (`^`) match the text "/span", followed by any number of whitespace characters (`\s*`), followed by any number of any type of character (`.*`).  The parenthesis tells it to capture the last part for later use.

Comment: I am doing this in js - so should I do something like this: var test = new RegExp("^/span\s*(.*)"); and test will have the styletext value??

Comment: I don't really know Java, but based on a quick look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html, it looks like you'd want something like `Pattern p = new Pattern;` and then `var test = p.Matches("^/span\s*(.*)", inputString);`

Comment: I see your pattern has changed in the original question too, so that regex will no longer work.  This should do it: `<span\s?[^>]*>[^>]*>(.*)`  ("<span" then an optional whitespace, then any number of non-">" characters, then ">", then any number of non-">" characters again, then ">", then remember everything after that)